# Is it discrimination that our work Christmas party is not at a time I, as a part time worker, can go?

Tags: united-kingdom, part-time

I work part time and my work Christmas party is at a time I don't work. Everyone who does work at that time gets paid to go to the party, a free drink and dinner - this doesn't seem fair?

Comment: Have you been told that you cannot charge the time?

Comment: Are you required to go to the party?

Comment: All Christmas-parties I ever experienced in 20 years where out of work-hours, nobody got paid and attendance was optional. What´s wrong with a free drink and dinner?

Comment: It sounds like you're upset that the party has been planned at a time when you are not able to attend: everyone else is getting a free meal, but you are not. Is that the case? Can you clarify exactly what you're asking about? The answer to "is it discrimination" is probably "no" if you mean discrimination in a legal sense, but it's not clear if that's what you mean or not.

Comment: You are not allowed to join them?

Comment: Do you want to go to the party?

Comment: Have you asked if you can attend even though you're not scheduled to work at that time? How many other workers might this affect? If it's more than a few, maybe they would consider scheduling a separate event for that shift.

Answer (score 3):

Is it discrimination? No.

They didn't schedule the party so as to specifically exclude you. They scheduled it to accommodate the majority of the employees and to minimize any impact to the business if the party is scheduled during work hours.

Don't take it personally. If you can attend, then do so. If you can't, then don't.

Answer (score 2):

So If I understand correctly, the Christmas party starts during the afternoon and will probably extend to after work-hours? You only work the morning? Attendance is optional?

- So nobody will get any more pay then what they would usually get.
- Nobody gets any less pay then they would usually get.
- Everybody gets free drinks and food.
- Some people get some hours socializing rather than sitting behind their desks.

You may perceive as unfair that you don´t get to spend some payed time away from your desk, but that´s just a result of your schedule and time parties usually are. It´s not like you get any disadvantage. Just like when you don´t work on Mondays, but Mondays is a public holiday ... though luck.

I would just go with it. If you complain you will definitely be seen as begrudging by your colleagues and the best you could hope for is to spoil the fun for everyone. Its not like they are going to pay you to treat you to a free dinner!

Comment: Defiantly or definitely?

Comment: @Solar Mike definitely definitely, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> Is it discrimination that our work Christmas party is not at a time I,
>   as a part time worker, can go?

No, that is not at all discrimination in the legal sense.

> Everyone who does work at that time gets paid to go to the party, a
>   free drink and dinner - this doesn't seem fair?

It doesn't seem completely fair to me either. I'm guessing that you are still permitted to attend the party, so you aren't being made to miss out on the free drink and dinner part - just the paid time off part.

Rather than trying to claim "discrimination", you might inquire what the company is doing for those who cannot attend for reasons similar to yours.

Perhaps they are doing something for those like you, perhaps not. The answer may be that they are doing nothing, and it still may feel unfair, but at least you'll know for sure.